# Digital Ocean Internal Server Error on django project

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, digital-ocean

I have a django project which i launched on digital ocean. This project uses a costume 404 page. The site works well except that when ever i type in a page that does not exit instead of getting a 404 page, i just get 'internal server error'. Locally, the 404 page works well.

Comment: This means that your 404 page somehow contains an error. Can you share the code for displaying your custom 404 page?

Comment: Thanks @Griffioen, the error came from me. It is now working.